# Implementing Simple CAPTCHA in Bottle

Tags: python, web, captcha, bottle

I am trying to understand the best way to implement a simple CAPTCHA using the python web framework bottle.  So far all I have discovered are people asking for plug and go captcha libraries, or 'actually secure' complex generative image CAPTCHA implementations that make the code examples hard to understand.  I am interested in knowing what would be considered 'best practice' to implement the very basics of a CAPTCHA in a framework like Flask/Bottle:

- To send a specific and unique human-solvable problem to a user form.
- To track these problems and their correct answer to each user.
- To verify, upon receiving the form, that the problem assigned to that user has the correct answer.

This does not needs to be a robust implementation, for example it could be as simple as sending a simple arithmetic problem like 3+2 = ?.  At this point I don't have a grasp on the basics of how to properly implement even this.

So far I have implemented a very basic captcha which only works on text, and while I have said I do not need it to be secure to understand the principle, my current method has no way to become anything secure.

**The template:**

```
<form action='/form' method='post'>
    {{ints[0]}} + {{ints[1]}}
    <input name='answer' value='{{ints[0] + ints[1]}}' type='hidden'>
    <input type='text' name='captcha'>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

**The python bottle web app:**

```
from bottle import default_app, route, template, post, request
import random


@route('/')
def test_display():
    ints = random.randint(0,9),random.randint(0,9)
    formhtml = template("temp", ints=ints)

    return formhtml

@route('/form', method='POST')
def print_form():
    value = request.forms.get('answer')
    if value != request.forms.get('captcha'):
        return 'Wrong.'
    else:
        return 'Correct.'

application = default_app()
```

I am simply storing the answer to each generated captcha inside a hidden input field on the user's form.  This gets around any server side storage, but I know intuitively that storing the exact solution to the problem on the client **completely defeats the purpose of a CAPTCHA**.  So this won't do.

What I need is some sort of server side session storage for any user that gets a page with a form on it, and I need this to be somehow tracked so when they POST the form the server knows who posted it.  Be cause frameworks are so abstracted, and tutorials are not very good at explaining the underlying ideas, I don't really have a good grasp on what I can do or what tools are available to me to implement this.

Bottle may not even be easily capable of this task (I doubt this though), so suggestions for simpler python solutions if there is one are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without any kind of session with the user. just put the HASH value of the answer

Something like HASH(ANSWER+CURRENT_TIME). When you check the answer check that time is recent and you are good to go

```
@route('/form', method='POST')
def print_form():
    value = request.forms.get('answer')
    time_given_by_server =  request.forms.get('time_given_by_server')#also hidden

    captcha = hashlib.sha1("%s%s"% (request.forms.get('captcha'), time_give_by_server)).hexdigest()
    if value != catcha or time.time()-time_given_by_server > (60*5):#5 mintues is ok i guess...
        return 'Wrong.'
    else:
        return 'Correct.'
```

Of course you'll have to prepare "answer" in test_display using the hash and so on...

Comment: I am going to essentially use what you have shown me here.  The time gate is interesting, although I am not sure what you are trying to get at by rejecting the form if its older than 5 minutes.  Wouldn't we want to check to see that some *minimum* time has passed to filter bots that instantly fill the form, even if the answer is correct?

Comment: @MylesGallagher - Minimum time is nice, but the five minute limit is against reply attacks

Comment: Oh I see, to prevent spamming the same form over and over again.